# Coefficient not estimable voom r

Tags: r, matrix, linear-regression, model.matrix, rna-seq

I have a DGEList x containing genes in rows and samples in columns (multiple samples for same patient). I have no NA in my data because I used complete.case function(). I create the design matrix in this way:

```
design <- model.matrix(~0 + f1  + f2  + f3 + f4 + f5 + f6 + f7 + f8 + f9 + age + gender, data=x$samples)
```

where f are some features (in this case I have 9 features). These are just numeric vector not factor, so in the design matrix each feature has only one single column (equal for age). Instead gender is a factor (M or F). So in the design matrix it has 2 columns.

When I Call:

```
v    <- voom(x, design, plot = F)
```

it returns:

> Coefficients not estimable: f7 f8 f9 age genderF genderM
>   Warning message: Partial NA coefficients for 17080 probe(s)
>   I see that it's ok until the totale value passed to model.matrix are 6 no more.

Why ??

When I call: `vfit <- lmFit(v, design)`
it returns the same warning and the columns corresponding (f7 f8 f9 age genderF genderM) in the vift$coefficents are only with NA.

My other question is ? **How many parameters is correct to use in a model.matrix** ? Because I see that passing 6 parameters in the model.matrix cause no errors, so it's ok, but no more 6. When I use more than 6 values inside model.matrix(), it returns the problem previously described.

Comment: What package does function `voom` come from? The last version of package `limma` is 2.10.7 dated `2007-09-24 10:09`. And the package needs R <= 2.5.1.

Comment: `model.matrix` can handle *much* more than 9 or 10 (or 90 or 100) variables. The error is somewhere else.

Comment: @RuiBarradas from library(edgeR)

Comment: @RuiBarradas in addition is ok to put the confounder in the right part of the formula ? (gender and age)

Comment: Yes, it is, it's the right place where to put it.

Comment: Ok thanks, so I don't know what is the problem here; because the design it's ok. The problem is in the output of lmFit()

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/215948/discussion-between-will-and-rui-barradas).

Comment: @Will I have the same problem. What does that ended to be?

Comment: @Omar113 I didn't remember exactly how I solved the problem, but I remember I just removed all the NA in the DGEList x, in the all dimensions (x$samples, x$etc....)